# Index out of Range error when creating sections in TableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I have TableView inside a ViewController that is populated using JSON data:

The following is the structure of the JSON including sections:

```
struct TabSections {
    let name : String
    let collection : [TabCollection]
}

struct TabCollection: Decodable {
    let number, person, status: String
    let maker: String
}
```

The following is how the TableView and tabs populate with the JSON data:

```
var sections = [TabSection]()

private func fetchJSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php"),
        let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "name=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let res = try decoder.decode([TabCollection].self, from: data)
            let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.status })
            let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
            self.sections = keys.map({TabSections(name: $0, collection: grouped[$0]!)})

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.receiptTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}
```

The error occurs under `numberOfRowsInSection` and stops on the first line where section is defined:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]

    return section.collection.count


}
```

I cannot seem to understand why I receiving `Index out of range` on the line `let section`

Comment: Show your `numberOfSections` method.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have a `numberOfSections` method which means the table view defaults to 1 section. Since your data model can have no elements initially, you need to implement `numberOfSections` to return the number of elements in `sections`.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, really quick side question, if for example the JSON data contains a status for some records called "Processed" and another called "In Progress" can the sections which are based on the status say for "Ready" and "Not Ready" instead?

Comment: That's a completely different question. Close this one and post a new question with relevant details if you are unable to find the solution. But yes, you can change it however you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that extension for `Collection` fo safely retrieving an element from collection.

```
extension Collection {
    /// Returns the element at the specified index if it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

So your `numberOfRowsInSection` will look like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let section = sections[safe: section] else { 
        return 0 
    }
    return section.collection.count
}
```